# how to launch evince at 100% zoom, or other pdf-viewing solution

Tags: gnome

I'm going through a bunch of PDFs viewing and then renaming.

I want to open each PDF at 100% zoom when I double-click it from nautilus.  Currently it opens at 59%.  I have to resize the window every time.

The application seems to call itself "Document Viewer".  As far as I can tell, this is an unhelpful indirect name for `evince`.  But I am not sure, because GNOME as a whole is trying to be "clever" about everything.

I've tried "Save Current Settings as Default", but that doesn't have the desired effect.

I've also tried `gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default zoom 1.0` based on eg https://askubuntu.com/questions/606838/configure-evince-to-open-maximized-with-100-zoom-level .  The `gesttings` command  did not produce an error.  But nor did it change evince's behaviour.

I'm open to a generic X11 solution, and reserving an area of the screen for this.  I'm also open to a solution involving `evince`, or how `nautilus` launches it, or a different graphical shell or PDF viewer.  Preferably applications available with debian 10.

Ideally I'd like a graphical shell which can give 100% previews and inline renames with F2.  This would give a quick workflow for view-renaming whole folders of scanned papers one after the other.

I'd also be interested in socio-cultural explanations of the confluence of factors that resulted in such a severe and basic failure: opening a PDF from the graphical file browser does not result in a readable rendering, and requires the user to resize the window.

Screen is 3840x2160.

Comment: There is no known solution to this problem and I agree it is a serious flaw with Evince (or whatever they call it).  The answer listed below works only for the active document but does not carry over to other documents.  Also the interface is the worst ever.  I wish Gnome would just go away.

Answer (score 2):

"Save Current Settings as Default" works for me on F33. I didn't change any of the other Gnome settings. I use a couple of different monitors with different resolutions and it doesn't give me any issues. I don't know if Debian handles Evince differently; I haven't used Debian for ages. Not a lot of help, sorry.

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.